# Need help: multiple request throttling

Tags: error, nginx, request

I have an issue in the CraftCMS back office when I try to export all entries.

When I try to export all the entries in expanded mode

[image]

it takes ~1min but every minute the back office send another request **bundle-office/actions/users/session-info**,

[image]

when this second request is sent, the export request is timing out and return a 502 Bad Gateway.

[image]

**Does anyone know how craft / nginx handle those requests and how could I fix this issue ?**

Thanks

Comment: What's the error log saying? 502 is usually a sign that FPM didn't return any data because of an error... you might be hitting PHP's ``max_execution_time``, the default is 30 seconds.

Comment: I don't have logs access :/
In the request timings, the request stops at 2min
In my php_info I have php `max_execution_time` set to 360s

Comment: ``memory_limit`` perhaps?